# Looping through text view in Android

Tags: android, textview

I want to get all description of the routes in the emulator. I am only getting one description in the emulator but in the log cat I got all the description!!

```
for (Route route : routes) {

        text1Status.setText(route.getDescription());
            Log.d(TAG, route.getDescription());
    }
```

thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using the `.setText()` method which overrides all the previous content you might have got. That's why you've the feeling you're seeing just one (the last one probably). Try using `.append()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

use append method of TextView, something like this

```
for (Route route : routes) {
    text1Status.append(route.getDescription() + "\n");
    Log.d(TAG, route.getDescription());
}
```

I hope you serve